# What is the energy transformation in the fission reaction?

Tags: atomic-physics, binding-energy

According to one of my physics textbooks, when U-235 absorbs a neutron it becomes unstable and soon fissions into two separate atoms. The forces driving these two atoms apart are electrostatic forces of repulsion. Thus the kinetic energy that these atoms receive comes from the electrostatic interaction. This kinetic energy is later transformed into heat in an atomic reactor when two released atoms slow down colliding with the molecules of water.

What role does the binding energy play in this scenario? Does it mean that some part of the binding energy is transformed into kinetic through electrostatic repulsion?

Comment: Pl. qoute the details of the text-book for advice leading to correction or otherwise

Comment: @drvrm thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can quote the book only in Russian. I am not sure this will help much.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.
The neutron absorbed by the unstable U235 nucleus makes its decay via fission much more probable.  The U235 nucleus then decays into two smaller nuclei and a few neutrons which overall have a higher binding energy per nucleon than the U235 nucleus.  This decrease in binding energy manifests itself as kinetic energy of the fission fragments (and some electromagnetic radiation) and this is the source of the energy in a nuclear reactor.

---

To illustrate that the reduction in the coulomb repulsion does contribute to the kinetic energy of the fission fragments I will use the semi-empirical mass formula which is described in the article [Weizsaecker Formula](http://www.nuclear-power.net/nuclear-power/fission/weizsaecker-formula-semi-empirical-mass-formula/) and can be used to give a reasonable value for the binding energy of large nucleii.

[image]

Consider the following possible fission reaction:

$$^{235}_{\;92}\text{U} + ^{1}_{0}\text{n} \rightarrow ^{139}_{\;56}\text{Ba}  + ^{94}_{36}\text{Kr}  +3 ^{1}_{0}\text{n}$$

The first term represents the contribution to the binding energy of the strong nuclear force between the nucleons (neutrons and protons) in the nucleus.

For the chosen reaction it is $3704$ MeV for the Uranium nucleus and $2191+1481 = 3672$ MeV for the Barium and Krypton nucleii.
Not much difference because the number of nucleons is roughly the same.

The first term overestimates the binding energy due to a number of factors with the next two terms due the surface and due to coulomb repulsion considered below.

The surface (second) term is there because the nucleons in the surface of a nucleus do not bond as strongly as those in the bulk.
For the chosen reaction it is $-679$ MeV for the Uranium nucleus and $-478 -368 = -847$ MeV for the Barium and Krypton nucleii.
So due to the surface effect the two nucleii produced as a result of the fission reaction are relatively **less** stable then the Uranium nucleus because the surface area of the two fission products is greater than that of the Uranium nucleus by $168$ MeV.

The coulomb repulsion (third) term is is $-975$ MeV for the Uranium nucleus and $-430 -203 = -342$ MeV for the Barium and Krypton nucleii.
So due to coulomb repulsion the two nucleii produced as a result of the fission reaction are relatively **more** stable then the Uranium nucleus by $342$ MeV.

Overall there is a gain in the binding energy of $342 - 168 = 174$ MeV after the fission even though the combined surface area of the fission fragments is greater than that of the Uranium nucleus.
It is this gain in binding energy which manifests itself as the kinetic energy of the fission fragments.

Comment: <The U235 nucleus then decays into two smaller nuclei and a few neutrons which overall have a lower binding energy than the U235 nucleus.>.....@Farcher;  i think its opposite the smaller nuclei have higher binding energies.

Comment: @drvrm I have made the change and added "per nucleon". but in the process deleted part of my answer.  Is there a way of undeleting?

Comment: @drvrm  I have updated my answer.

Comment: <It is this gain(174 MeV) in binding energy which manifests itself as the kinetic energy of the fission fragments>  @Farcher , the number should be around 200 MeV(more than  174MeV) ,as BE is now well known in literature one can use the info.Moreover coulomb contribution  may not contribute in actual  binding the nucleons.

Comment: @drvrm  I agree that the total energy released is of the order of 200 MeV.  If you look at this web page you will note that my approximate value for the energy released from the initial fission is correct.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nucene/u235chn.html#c2 Then what happens is that more energy is released because the fission fragments themselves are unstable and release energy when they decay.

Answer (score 1):

> The forces driving these two atoms apart are electrostatic forces of repulsion. Thus the kinetic energy that these atoms receive comes from the electrostatic interaction. This kinetic energy is later transformed into heat in an atomic reactor when two released atoms slow down colliding with the molecules of water.

I think in nuclear processes one should give importance to  strong forces of attraction  of nuclear nature rather than electrostatic forces between charged nucleons/or role of atomic electrons.

The enormous quantity of energy  release in a fission can be qualitatively   understood with the help of binding energy or binding fraction of a nucleus
which is ratio of Binding energy and mass number(B/A) usually called f(b).
*For Uranium f(b)=7.6 MeV per nucleon.*

The fragments produced by fission have mass numbers near the middle of the periodic table  *having f(b) of the range 8.5 MeV-*

Thus by the  breaking up approx. **0.9 MeV energy per nucleon** gets released ;which comes out to be around **212 Mev** for Uranium fission.
Alternatively Q value of  fission reaction can also be estimated which comes to **201 Mev** for Uranium absorbing a thermal neutron and breaking into Ba and Kr with 3 neutrons.

*I wish to point out that the nuclear fission process itself gets a good amount of energy released due to changes in binding energy of nucleons involved and electrostatic energy conversion does not play any significant role in this nuclear exoergic process.*

Therefore **one must revise the picture of Electrostatic energy  going** to Kinetic energy and then thermal energy of the fission process- as their contribution is minimal.

Comment: I am interested in the statement that the contribution due to the electrostatic forces is minimal.  Will you elaborate?

Comment: The  statement about 'minimal" contribution comes from the energy range in which these two forces electromagnetic and nuclear work. the former is in the eV or keV range but latter starts at Mev - for example an Alpha particle has about 7 MeV  binding energy per nucleon and electrostatic repulsion between protons will be a fraction of electron volt.Some body asked me about electrostatic repulsion of electron cloud when a proton strikes a nucleus(atom) ,estimated to be a few  keV naturally we concentrate on the N-N interaction rather than p-p repulsive force

Comment: @drvrm true, but electrostatic energy depends on Z^2, which starts to become significant for large Z nuclei. I didn't think it can be (totally) ignored in this case.

Comment: @drvrm I cannot find a reference to the 3% of the total energy released in the link that you provided.

Comment: < For uranium-235 (total mean fission energy 202.5 MeV), typically ~169 MeV appears as the kinetic energy of the daughter nuclei, which fly apart at about 3% of the speed of light, due to Coulomb repulsion.>@Farcher, you  have pointed  the error... actually its 3% of the  speed of light(with which the fragments fly  due to coulomb repulsion), i am correcting the comments.

Comment: @Farcher,  In a typical fission break up the energy share is  about 81.4 MeV to the heavier one and 93.1 to the lighter fragment.. i do not think it  can come from electrostatic repulsion of protons as the major contributor is the B.E. difference.